# React, Strapi & GraphQL: React doens't load the contecnt, screen totaly white and no errors in the development server

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, strapi

I am trying to implement Strapi on my react website. So i did some code and i didn't get an error but my screen is still white.

Index.js:[image.js screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUlHO.png)

Portfolio.jsx
[Proftolio.jsx file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1329.png)

The only thing what i can found is in elemenemt inspect:[element inspect screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwzoJ.png)

Does anyone know what is wrong in my code? I've got the content out of the playground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the "attributes" in your "map" and where you are using: `{portfolio.title}` should be `{portfolio.attributes.title}` thats what fixed mine untill I just broke it again trying for images...

Comment: Thank you, it works!

I changed data.portfolios.data.map and portfolio.attributes.title